# How to read car ECU File by php

Tags: hex

I have tuned car ecu files without file extension, so how will i read that file to get written values like car "make,model,BHP,Engine,Year" etc.

This is the reference site developed on php. they can read ECU file to get values of racing car. from the below picture, i have uploaded a tuned file and they have read my file and extracted data from my file. Make, Model, Engine, BHP data they have found by reading my file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN9au.png)

I have found the ECU file is written in Hexadecimal format. so how can i retrive the car values like (engine type, model, make, BHP etc from the tuned ECU files by php)

Any Clue Please ?

This website has this feature: https://tuning-software.com
you can login and upload a tuned files then the website will read the file and populate values into form.

username: ronymia
password: 12345678

this is the tuned file: https://file.io/xWGZ7epBClt3

I tried to know the file types and how to read it but didn't get any proper solution.